# How to replace part of shortlink with nothing

Tags: customization, shortlink

I am attempting to shorten the wp_get_shortlink. I want to remove the "http://" which is unnecessary.

I have attempted the regular php way of (Replace("http://"," " )); but it seems WordPress has a different way of doing replace?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
  $post_url =  wp_get_shortlink(Replace("http://"," " ));
  $post_title = get_the_title();
```

Then later:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=**$post_url**&text=$post_title"  onclick="window.open(this.href,'popupwindow','width=800,height=300,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable'); return false;" target="_blank">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace a string within the result, you've got it in the function's arguments. Nothing WordPress-specific here.

```
$post_url = str_replace( 'http://', '', wp_get_shortlink() );
```

Comment: Hi Milo,
Thanks for taking a stab at it, but this results in no link displayed -- Just the title

Comment: if the second part is literally your code, then that is not valid php. you need to `echo $post_url` to output it. the code above is tested and definitely works.